# Is it possible to cause memory corruption in C# using the unsafe keyword

Tags: c#, clr, heap-corruption, stack-corruption

If I get a pointer to a first element of an array, can I just go beyond the range of the array and write arbitrary data to the GC heap memory, effectively breaking the heap and the garbage collector, or are there any safe guards in the CLR against this kind of messing.

Code example:

```
unsafe {
    int[] intArray = new int[100];
    fixed (int* ptr = intArray) {
        *(ptr - 42) = 456872;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to cause memory corruption in this way, potentially corrupting the CLRs own data structures?

Comment: Can you show a piece of code what you think will *break CLR*?

Comment: Possibly you can. It depends on the access flags of the page. But if the page belongs to the managed heap, I'm pretty sure that you will get no error while accessing it.

Comment: Unsafe code is, well, unsafe

Comment: You can break it [even without unsafe code](http://sriramsakthivel.wordpress.com/2014/12/27/breaking-the-clr-type-safety/) as shown in my recent blog post. But it all depends on what do you mean by the word *break*.

Comment: Sure, the basic property of any code that uses pointers is that it is *unverifiable*.  The jitter will refuse to compile it unless this code runs in full trust mode.

Comment: Define "break". With `unsafe` code, you can certainly do unsafe things, including causing your process to stop working. But I would've thought that'd be obvious. So maybe you have something else more specific in mind? The question seems pretty broad as it stands now, and not very useful.

Comment: Good question "how unsafe is unsafe?". I'm pretty sure the answer is yes - you can corrupt the heap / stack with unsafe code, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Justin Don't know? OP just shown how to corrupt the gc heap with this line `*(ptr - 42) = 456872;` I'm not sure what OP is asking here by *Is it possible to cause memory corruption in this way ?* because he just have the snippet which corrupts the heap.